# how to calculate sea route using google api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

In my project I pass the origin address and destination address, but not get the distance.
origin address-:south africa
destination address-:india
url-:https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=south%20africa&destination=india&key=GOOGLE_API_KEY

Response-:

> {
>      "geocoded_waypoints" : [
>         {
>            "geocoder_status" : "OK",
>            "place_id" : "ChIJURLu2YmmNBwRoOikHwxjXeg",
>            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
>         },
>         {
>            "geocoder_status" : "OK",
>            "place_id" : "ChIJkbeSa_BfYzARphNChaFPjNc",
>            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
>         }
>      ],
>      "routes" : [],
>      "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
>   }

noroutes found so how can get distance between two country

Answer (score 0):

Get the distance between the two countries?  Don't use google maps.  Create a Location object for each and call Location.distanceTo().  Google maps would only possibly help if you wanted a land route.